# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Someone can give a help to solve this problem

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I try to add a jsp file and make an http request on it, i got this error on the stderr.txt log file
Can someone give me a solution.
Thanks in advance

---

```
 SYS_ERR: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IErrorHandlingPolicy;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ICompilerRequestor;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IProblemFactory;)V
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:342)
 SYS_ERR:   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 SYS_ERR:   at com.adventnet.appmanager.filter.ExtProdIntegFilter.doFilter(ExtProdIntegFilter.java:130)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 SYS_ERR:   at com.adventnet.appmanager.filter.AAMFilter.doFilter(AAMFilter.java:118)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 
...
...
 SYS_ERR: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IErrorHandlingPolicy;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ICompilerRequestor;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IProblemFactory;)V
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:442)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
 SYS_ERR:   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
 SYS_ERR:   ... 46 more
```

Comment: Which OS are you using and how did you install Tomcat? It seems you have an incompatible version of the ECJ compiler.

Comment: OS : Windows Server 2012, i had a VM all installed on, there is a jar file ecj-3.7.jar

Comment: 3.7 is a pretty old version. How did you install Tomcat and what version did you install? ECJ is distributed with Tomcat (in the `lib` directory) and numbered accordingly to Eclipse's release train releases: the first version of Tomcat 8.5 use ECJ 4.6.1.

Comment: I'm working in a pre-installed machine !

Comment: the tomcat version is 7.x